# How to map ImmutableArray without getting it cast to IEnumerable which is not thread safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq

So I'm working in a multithreaded environment and I wan't to use ImmutableArray all the time because it's thread safe.

Unfortunately, ImmutableArray implements thread unsafe interfaces and so Select method from LINQ returns IEnumerable.

This way, my thread safe variable becomes thread unsafe.
How do I map from ImmutableArray to ImmutableArray?

Comment: How is mapping over an immutable collection not thread-safe?

Comment: I'm not deeply familiar with multithreaded programming but I know IEnumerable is not thread safe so when it gets returned I'm not sure how the next computation (even casting back to ImmutableArray) would work regarding thread safety

Comment: You might create your own Select extension method for ImmutableArray, which will return another ImmutableArray.

Comment: I'm surprisef there isn't something like this already. I'm also unsure how would I imeplement it to be thread safe

Comment: The `IEnumerable<T>` interface does not guarantee the underlying implementation is thread-safe, but iterating over an immutable collection is safe. There is no `IThreadSafeEnumerable<T>` interface in the BCL and the approach taken there is to simply document which types are thread-safe, so you could simply document when your methods return sequences over immutable collections.

Comment: Immutable collections are **immutable**, so if you are not using reflection to mess with the underlying state, they should prevent mutation by design. I am not aware of any LINQ methods which would mutate the underlying collection, either, but even if you did write such a method for a, say, `IList<T>`, I don't see how it would possibly mutate a `ImmutableArray<T>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that there are a lot of misunderstandings behind this question. You need to go look at the source code for the `Select` method and learn about the `yield` keyword.

Second, LINQ methods are made to be short-lived. You have various threads doing various processing tasks. Are you using a pipeline situation, where you want to transform data in one thread and pass the result to another thread? You have to be careful with the `yield` keyword in that situation; essentially, you need to flush (er, realize, for lack of a better word) your collections before passing them to the next thread so that the actual work is done in the present thread. In that scenario, object ownership kicks in and you don't need thread-safe collections.

In short, the enumerable returned from calling `Select` on `ImmutableArray` is perfectly thread-safe. You can realize it at any point and it won't give you any errors. Of course it will only iterate through the data that was contained in your collection at the time you called `Select`. It won't know anything about newly assigned instances.